# How can I display an HTML button using the return from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I trying to have my function return HTML button tags that will be displayed on the page like so:

[image]

(without the hover thing)

The problem is that as you can see every row has different buttons, so I wanted to make a function that takes in the parameter the "category" of the row, for example the "Games" row has 2 buttons: Modify and Delete.

Here's my javascript code:

```
function Category(cat) {
    if (cat == "games") {
        let innerhtml = `<div className='game_buttons'> <button className='modify'>Modify</button> <button className='delete'>Delete</button> </div>`
        return innerhtml
    }


    if (cat == "upcoming") {
        let innerhtml = `<div className='game_buttons'>  <button className='released'>Released</button> <button className='modify'>Modify</button> <button className='delete'>Delete</button> </div>`
        return innerhtml
    }


    if (cat == "featured") {
        let innerhtml = `<div className='game_buttons'> <button className='delete'>Delete</button> </div>`
        return innerhtml
    }
}
```

I placed that same function where I need it to be displayed, like so :

```
                    <div className='game_buttons'>
                        {Category("games")}
                    </div>
```

But I get this :
[image]

So how could I display this buttons instead of just getting the HTML tags as text?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using `React`. React escapes HTML strings by default. If you want to display HTML, you need to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop - https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml . However, this begs the question, if you are using React, just have your `Category` function be a React component, and have it return more JSX. Then just render it and pass a `cat` prop. `function Category({ cat }) { if (...) return <div ... /> }` ... `<Category cat="games" />`

Comment: Yes I am using react and as you probably saw I am quite new to it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React purposefully makes [injecting HTML strings cumbersome](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to try and steer you towards ["thinking in React."](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Here, this means just creating another component that conditionally renders the content you want as [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

```js
function Category(props) {
    if (props.cat === "games") {
        return (
            <div className="game_buttons">
                <button className="modify">Modify</button>
                <button className="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    if (props.cat === "upcoming") {
        return (
            <div className="game_buttons">
                <button className="released">Released</button>
                <button className="modify">Modify</button>
                <button className="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    if (props.cat === "featured") {
        return (
            <div className="game_buttons">
                <button className="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then, render `Category` and pass in your `cat` prop:

```js
<Category cat="games" />
```

Comment: Yup, I corrected that after I read your comment and the documentation you sent me. Thanks a lot!